# Can we expose public properties of a webservice on the client side?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, vbscript, getter-setter

I understand that webservices are stateless. I want to know if there is any way we can expose the public properties (getters and setters) of a webservice on the client side (client side being a vb consumer not javascript)?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can "expose" from a web service are the `[WebMethod]`.

---

You might access your web service with code like the following:

```
Dim svc as New WebReference.MyWebService()
Dim result As Integer = svc.GetSomeInteger()
svc.SetSomeInteger(result)
Dim result2 As Integer = svc.GetSomeInteger()
```

You may think that you have created an instance of the web service class. You have not. You have only created an instance of the proxy class in your VB.NET code. In the above code, each call to the web service goes through the same client proxy instance, but will go to a different instance of the server-side web service class.

Even if the web service had properties, or just fields, since you would have a different instance of the web service for each call, you would have a different version of "SomeInteger" each time.

Answer (score 0):

Web services are method-based, so they're not designed to access properties.

But there's no reason you couldn't make GetX/SetX methods which are exposed like regular service methods - just make sure you include the `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Joe. If I use functions, the state of the variable/properties is not maintained. Example: Webservice has a variable a =5. I have a 'set' function to set the value to 10. Now in my next line of client code, if I access a, its the original value 5.

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot reuse the instance of the service itself alive after the first call happens. Only thing I can think of is to do something kind of hacky, like keep a static Dictionary inside your service class, and keep the instances alive. Then you'd need to communicate a unique key for that instance back to the client, and have the client pass it back with each future request, and the service would then retrieve the specific instance and fire the request from there instead of the active instance.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you will need to use get/set methods instead of properties.

As for accessing the web service from JavaScript, just specify the method name in the URL and do an XmlHttpRequest.